# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>' to 'NSFetchRequest'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I always get this runtime error when I start my app using the CoreData framework. I followed precisely the instructions to set up the FetchRequest but I keep getting this error.

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>' (0x7feb68884da0) 
to 'NSFetchRequest' (0x7feb68884e40).
```

Here I set up the FetchRequest in the View I want to use it.

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: NotificationsItem.getAllNotificationsItems()) var notificationsItems:FetchedResults<NotificationsItem>
```

And here is how I set it up in my NotificationsItem class

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

public class NotificationsItem: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var createdAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var type: String?
}

extension NotificationsItem {
    static func getAllNotificationsItems() -> NSFetchRequest<NotificationsItem> {
        let request:NSFetchRequest<NotificationsItem> = NotificationsItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<NotificationsItem>

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        return request
    }
}
```

Why is this code keep getting this error even if it works perfectly in the instructors copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the top of your NSManagedObject class definition

```
//This need to be declared here
@objc(NotificationsItem)

public class NotificationsItem: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
...
```

And make sure to set the Codegen of the class to `Manual/None`

Comment: I added @objc(NotificationsItems) to the top of my NSManagedObject but still get the runtime error. the Codegen of the class is Manual/None aswell

Comment: Your class name is "NotificationsItem" without s at the end right?

Comment: Oh no you were right it works!! I thought I have to add the @objc(...) at the first row inside of my class. Thanks for your help sir !